# Очень медленно работают ПАРАЛЛЕЛЬНЫЕ Pthreads в Linux под VirtualBox

Tags: windows, c, linux, virtualbox, pthread

Компьютер 4 CPU I5-2500 3.3 GHz 4GB RAM Windows 7 64-bit, VirtualBox 4.1.6

В VirtualBox создана виртуальная машина 4 CPU (100%) 1 GB RAM все галочки по поводу ресурсов виртуализации поставлены.

OS Ubuntu 10.04 ядро 2.6.32-37-generic #81-Ubuntu SMP  x86_64 GNU/Linux gcc 4.4.3

Программа на Си запускает 2 потока (pthread_create()) которые параллельно заполняют массив из 10000000 long (64 разряда), вызывая rand(). Первый поток заполняет первые 5000000 элементов, а второй другие 5000000. Потоки выполняются **1674** (первый) и **1681** (второй) миллисекунд. В сумме (измерение в main, который запускает их и дожидается по pthread_join()) **1682** мс.

**Далее самое интересное**

Запускаемые последовательно, т.е. pthread_create(); pthread_join(); pthread_create(); pthread_join(); они работают **значительно** быстрее. Первый **124**, а второй **102** мс. Общее время **226** мс.

Процессы (через fork()) с разделяемой (shared) памятью не пробовал, аналогичный объем работы в своем пространстве (по 5000000 rand() каждый) два процесса выполняют за **118** мс. каждый, а общее время на запуск и ожидание их в main **120** мс.

Из чего следует, что в случае с процессами VirtualBox реально использует несколько CPU.

Простое (без всяких распараллеливаний) заполнение всего массива из 10000000 элементов занимает **189** мс.

### Поиск в сети ничего не дал. Кто-нибудь наблюдал подобное поведение ?

ПОЧЕМУ возможно такое замедление ???

Наблюдается ли такое в VMware ?

***Как исправить ситуацию ?***

### **UPDATE**

Итак, ***проблема решена. Потоки на самом деле линейно ускоряются*** (до числа процессоров).

Все дело было в rand(). После замены на

```
long
rnd (long l)
{
    l = l * 1103515245 + 12345;
    return ((unsigned)(l/35536) % 32768);
}
```

все правильно заработало

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/tst$ ./pr
init (10000000 cells) in main seq 99 msec
thread #0 34 msec
thread #1 34 msec
total 2 seq threads 70 msec
thread #1 34 msec
thread #0 34 msec
total 2 par threads 35 msec
same (10000000 cells) in main seq 65 msec
child 1771 run 79 msec
child 1770 run 81 msec
1771 exit 0
1770 exit 0
parent total 84 msec
avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/tst$
```

Для интересующихся код программы

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <pthread.h>
#include  <sys/wait.h>
#include  <sys/time.h>

static long long
mtime()
{
  struct timeval t;

  gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
  long long mt = (long long)t.tv_sec * 1000 + t.tv_usec / 1000;
  return mt;
}

long
rnd (long l)
{
  l = l * 1103515245 + 12345;
  return ((unsigned)(l/35536) % 32768);
}

void 
fill_rnd (long *arr, int from, int cnt)
{
  cnt += from;
  while (from < cnt)
    arr[from++] = 
#if 0
      rand();
#else
  rnd(from);
#endif

}

struct arg {
  long *arr;
  int from, cnt, thno;
};

void *
run_fill (void *a)
{
  struct arg *p = (struct arg *)a;

  long long s = mtime();

  fill_rnd (p->arr,p->from,p->cnt);
  printf ("thread #%d %lld msec\n",p->thno,mtime()-s);
  pthread_exit((void *)0);
}

void *
mk_arg (long *arr, int from, int cnt, int tno)
{
  struct arg *a = malloc(sizeof(*a));

  a->arr = arr;
  a->from = from;
  a->cnt = cnt;
  a->thno = tno;

  return (void *)a;
}

#define NN 10000000

main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  long long  start;
  void *trc;  
  long *r2 = malloc(NN*sizeof(*r2));
  pthread_t th1, th2;
  int  rc = 0;

  // init pages seq all in main
  start = mtime();
  fill_rnd (r2,0,NN);
  printf ("init (%d cells) in main seq %lld msec\n",NN,mtime()-start);

  // 2 threads seq
  start = mtime();
  rc += pthread_create (&th1,NULL, run_fill, mk_arg(r2,0,NN/2,0));
  pthread_join(th1,&trc);
  rc += pthread_create (&th2,NULL, run_fill, mk_arg(r2,NN/2,NN/2,1));
  if (rc) {
    perror ("threads");
    exit(rc);
  }
  pthread_join(th2,&trc);
  printf("total 2 seq threads %lld msec\n",mtime()-start);

  // 2 threads par
  start = mtime();
  rc += pthread_create (&th1,NULL, run_fill, mk_arg(r2,0,NN/2,0));
  rc += pthread_create (&th2,NULL, run_fill, mk_arg(r2,NN/2,NN/2,1));
  if (rc) {
    perror ("threads");
    exit(rc);
  }
  pthread_join(th1,&trc);
  pthread_join(th2,&trc);
  printf("total 2 par threads %lld msec\n",mtime()-start);

  // seq all in main
  start = mtime();
  fill_rnd (r2,0,NN);
  //  fill_rnd (r2,0+NN/2,NN/2);
  printf ("same (%d cells) in main seq %lld msec\n",NN,mtime()-start);

  // in fork
  pid_t pid;
  int   j;

  start = mtime();
  for ( j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    if (fork())
      continue;
    fill_rnd (r2,j*NN/2,NN/2);
    printf ("child %d run %lld msec\n",getpid(),mtime()-start);
    exit (0);
  }
  while ((pid = wait(&rc)) > 0) 
    printf ("%d exit %d\n",pid,rc);
  printf ("parent total %lld msec\n",mtime()-start);

  exit (rc);
}
```

Кстати, в man-ах о подобном поведении rand() (random()) ни слова. В общем, ***век живи - век учись***

Comment: А гонки за ресурсы нигде быть не может? Например, при вызове функции rand()

Comment: ммм, а ошибки быть нигде не может ? 

а то 10млн вызовов rand и 10 млн записей 64битного числа в память всего за 189 мс как то очень быстро, вам не кажется ?

Comment: Выложи программу, я бы ее на нормальном линуксе прогнал.

Comment: В вашей виртуальной машине действительно указано, что у неё 2 процессора?

Comment: Да, действительно, их 4. Только что разобрался, **проблема в rand()**.
Видимо rand() делает локинг (или что-то вроде). Заменил на умножение-сложение-деление-остаток и все полетело с линейным ускорением.

Сейчас закрываю вопрос (для интересующихся выложу код).

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/drand48_r

Comment: @cy6erGn0m, спасибо, это понятно.

Поясню, как я "дошел до такой жизни". Я решил проверить, как ведет себя rand() (именно не thread-safe версия) в многопоточной среде (будет ли последовательность вырождаться ?). Вот и наткнулся на "необъяснимо" большое время выполнения.

Answer (score 2):

решение вынесено из вопроса:

Все дело было в `rand()`. После замены на

```
long
rnd (long l)
{
    l = l * 1103515245 + 12345;
    return ((unsigned)(l/35536) % 32768);
}
```

все правильно заработало

Comment: Я вижу, вы вплотную занялись реабилитацией старых вопросов. )